# How to display the date of each file as the first element of each lines with bash/awk?

Tags: awk, ksh, aix

I have 7 txt files which are the output of the df -m command on AIX 7.2.

I need to keep only the first column and the second column for one filesystem. So I do that :

```
cat *.txt | grep hd4 | awk '{print $1","$2}' > test1.txt
```

And the output is :

```
/dev/hd4,384.00
/dev/hd4,394.00
/dev/hd4,354.00
/dev/hd4,384.00
/dev/hd4,484.00
/dev/hd4,324.00
/dev/hd4,384.00
```

Each files are created from the crontab and their filenames are :

```
df_command-2019-09-03-12:50:00.txt
df_command-2019-08-28-12:59:00.txt
df_command-2019-08-29-12:51:00.txt
df_command-2019-08-30-12:52:00.txt
df_command-2019-08-31-12:53:00.txt
df_command-2019-09-01-12:54:00.txt
df_command-2019-09-02-12:55:00.txt
```

I would like to keep only the date on the filename, I'm able to do that :

```
test=df_command-2019-09-03-12:50:00.txt
echo $test | cut -d'-' -f2,3,4
```

outout :

```
2019-09-03
```

But I would like to put each date as the first element of each line of my test1.txt :

```
2019-08-28,/dev/hd4,384.00
2019-08-29,/dev/hd4,394.00
2019-08-30,/dev/hd4,354.00
2019-08-31,/dev/hd4,384.00
2019-09-01,/dev/hd4,484.00
2019-09-02,/dev/hd4,324.00
2019-09-03,/dev/hd4,384.00
```

Do you have any idea to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk '/hd4/ {split(FILENAME,a,"-");print a[2]"-"a[3]"-"a[4]","$1","$2}' *.txt > test1.txt
```

- `/hd4/` find line with `hd4`
- `split(FILENAME,a,"-")` splits the filename in to array `a` split by `-`
- `print a[2]"-"a[3]"-"a[4]","$1","$2` print year-month-date, field 1, field 2
- `> test1.txt` to file test1.txt

Answer (score 1):

Date output file : dates.txt

```
2019-08-20
2019-08-08
2019-08-01
```

File system data fsys.txt

```
/dev/hd4,384.00 
/dev/hd4,394.00 
/dev/hd4,354.00
```

`paste` can be used to append the files as columns. Use `-d` to specify comma as the separator.

```
paste -d ',' dates.txt fsys.txt
```